# Differential second order equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

Any hint at this:

$$y''\left( t\right) +\dfrac {1}{y^{2}\left( t\right) +a^{2}}=0$$

With initial conditions $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$ .
I've already tried multiplying by $y$', integrating and making 
$$y\left( t\right) =a \tan\left( s\right)$$
but it just getting worse.

Comment: What are $a$ and $s$?

Comment: $a$ is any real number and $s$ is a real variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the first integral right. Multiply with $2y'$ and integrate to get
$$
C=y'^2+2\int \frac{dy}{y^2+a^2}=y'^2+\frac2a\arctan\frac{y}{a}
$$ 
Now insert initial conditions to get $C=\frac2a\arctan\frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: As my Differential Equations tutor said, it can't be solved with simple methods, because it is solved with the energy conservation theorem, so it has to be approximated with the Taylor series of $arctan(t)$ or numerical methods.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wrote above. The conserved and thus constant-on-solutions energy function is $E(y,v)=\frac12v^2+\frac1a\arctan\frac ya$.